# Ошибка с ключом в таблице БД

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Я пытаюсь сделать библиотеку в виде БД и приложения с графическим интерфейсом (поэтому WPF проект), которое будет ей управлять. Пока что только начал делать наброски.

В SQL кодах для студентов, факультетов и групп стоит `Identity(1,1)`. База данных сделана с помощью Sql Server. Все классы созданы автоматически с помощью scaffold, добавил только свои конструкторы. Недавно только начал изучать БД, поэтому не понимаю, что с этим делать.

Выбрасывается исключение:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: "An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details."

> SqlException: Конфликт инструкции INSERT с ограничением FOREIGN KEY "FK_Groups_Faculty". Конфликт произошел в базе данных "Library", таблица "dbo.Faculties", column 'Id'.

Главное окно:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace Library
{ 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            using (Models.LibraryContext db = new Models.LibraryContext())
            {
                Models.Faculty faculty = new Models.Faculty("IIVT");
                db.Faculties.Add(faculty);
                Models.Group group=new Models.Group("VPR34",15);
                db.Groups.Add(group);
                Models.Student user1 = new Models.Student("Maxim", "Leo",group.Id, 14);
                Models.Student user2 = new Models.Student("Nikita", "Kolychev", group.Id, 25);

                // добавляем их в бд
                db.Students.Add(user1);
                db.Students.Add(user2);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Объекты успешно сохранены");    
            }
            Console.Read();
            InitializeComponent();                
        }
    }
}
```

Класс студент:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Library.Models
{
    public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            SCards = new HashSet<SCard>();
        }

        public Student(string FirstName, string LastName, int IdGroup,int Term)
        {
              this.FirstName = FirstName;
              this.LastName = LastName;
              this.IdGroup = IdGroup;
              this.Term = Term;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
        public int IdGroup { get; set; }
        public int Term { get; set; }

        public virtual Group IdGroupNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<SCard> SCards { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Класс факультет:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Library.Models
{
    public partial class Faculty
    {
        public Faculty()
        {
            Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
        }
        public Faculty(string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Класс группа

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Library.Models
{
    public partial class Group
    {
        public Group()
        {
            Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }
        public Group(string Name,int IdFaculty)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.IdFaculty = IdFaculty;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public int IdFaculty { get; set; }

        public virtual Faculty IdFacultyNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему в таблице Faculty нет строки с id 15. А вы пытаетесь на нее сослаться при вставке в Groups: **Models.Group group=new Models.Group("VPR34",15);**

Comment: Аа,я че то не обратил внимания.спасибо

Comment: хотя я поменял 15 на faculty.Id и ошибка не пропала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Identity(1,1)` означает, что айдишники генерируются в БД.
В этом случае Entity Framework при создании сущностей сперва задаёт им временные значения Id, а при сохранении их в БД методом `SaveChanges` они получают реальные значения.
Исходя из этого, вам не следует хоть как-то использовать в своём коде свойства `faculty.Id`, `group.Id`, `student.Id`. Вместо этого всегда задавайте навигационные свойства.

Вот такой код успешно сработает:

```
Faculty faculty = new Faculty { Name = "IIVT" };
db.Faculties.Add(faculty);

Group group = new Group { Name = "VPR34", IdFacultyNavigation = faculty };
db.Groups.Add(group);

Student user1 = new Student { FirstName = "Maxim", LastName = "Leo", IdGroupNavigation = group, Term = 14 };
Student user2 = new Student { FirstName = "Nikita", LastName = "Kolychev", IdGroupNavigation = group, Term = 25 };

db.Students.Add(user1);
db.Students.Add(user2);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Здесь я не использовал ваши конструкторы, а задал свойства. Обратите внимание на `IdFacultyNavigation = faculty` и `IdGroupNavigation = group`.

---

Тут можно многое написать и про общепринятый нейминг, и про конструкторы сущностей, но пока хватит.

Comment: снова вы мне помогли, большое спасибо